# how to give rights to user in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, sharepoint-designer

I am working on sharepoint 2013.I have 5 site pages which are linked to top links bars.I want to on 1 st Link..Named Ecommerce URL: http://www.123.com is linked to it and opens page which has 5 webpart.

What i want when some user suppose Richard click on the Ecommerce Links he will able to see the webpart for which he have right.I have to give him rights to view only 3 webparts out of 5.Can it be possible.

What solution i am thinking is to make 2 Usergroup

Example
1)abc-in abc add 1 user with name of nokia 
2) xyz -in xyhz add 1 user name Sony

Now I will give rights to abc when he clicks on Ecommerce to view only 1,2,3 Webpart out of 5 and to xyz user to give rights of 3,4,5 webparts.

Now how do I give rights to a user to see specific Webpart..I dont know that

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Target Audiences (Under Edit Web Part>Advanced) for each Web Part on the page.You can specify Users or Groups in it, When the page is rendered, the Web Part appears only to the people who are members of the audiences you specified.

[Reference and Steps](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)